# How to read pretrained weights of google inception v3 model from tensorflow to tflean?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I am currently trying to train google inception v3 model with TF learn. Tensorflow has provided the trained model over imagenet dataset. But it is not in a usual .tflearn format. I have gone through the documentation of tflearn, but I cannot find any description to convert tensorflow weights into TFlearn format. I know that the right place to ask this question is tflearn gihub page. But it is currently very busy with high number of open issues.
Could anyone point me to the correct direction?

Comment: The scripts usually come with the restore operation for eval. Did you try that?

Comment: I have downloaded the weights from the following website: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim
where it is given as zip file. one of the checkpoint for the version 3 is saved as binary. I am not sure how to lead this file for the front end library called TFlearn.

Comment: Restoring the inception from checkpoint is actually hard and not quite possible right now. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5036

Comment: But if it is difficult to load weights from checkpoint, how is it possible to retrain the final layers of inception v3 for another dataset that they explain in this tutorial? https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining